# adding delimiter to a file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to add a delimiter to a file, at particular positions for e.g. after no.s. I want to do this with sed can anyone help me

Comment: It would be useful if you could tell us what your file looks like and what you want the output to be.

Comment: my file is a simple text file with format "The no is 0 The no. is 1 " and so on. I want to change it into 'The no is 0 \n The no is 1\n' and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\) /\1\n/g' file.txt
```

It searches for a digit with a space after it and places a new line after the number.

Comment: what if it searches only a digit not a space after it. Please reply

Comment: @Shweta Then just remove the space from the sed expression and use: `sed 's/\([0-9]\)/\1\n/g' file.txt`. Note that if you have multiple digits in a number e.g. "The no is 123", it won't work.

Comment: Then you should use this: `sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([^0-9]\|$\)/\1\n\2/g' file` -- that looks for a digit followed by something that is either not a digit or end of line.

Comment: what should I do if I have to do more than one thing using sed. It seems that a sed command disables previous command's changes

Comment: @Shweta You can use `-e` for multiple sed expressions. e.g. `sed -e 's/\([0-9]\) /\1\n/g' -e 's/foo/bar/g' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you are looking for the next line '\n' and need to replace it with a Unit Separator `(hex \037) 0 \n`.

you can try the following:

```
sed -e "s/[\012]/[\037]0[\012]/g" testin.txt > testout.txt
```

and

```
sed -e 's/'$(echo "\012")'/'$(echo "\037")'0'$(echo "\012")'/g' testin.txt > testout.txt
```

also check [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/96577-help-sed-add-delimiter-new-field-each-row.html)